# Unable to produce data to hazelcast in apache camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel, hazelcast

I have the following route configured in apache-camel

```
  from("direct:hazelCast")
        .setHeader(HazelcastConstants.OPERATION, constant(HazelcastConstants.PUT_OPERATION))
        .toF("hazelcast:map:testHazel", HazelcastConstants.MAP_PREFIX);
```

But, when the above route is invoked I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null key is not allowed!
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:95)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.map.HazelcastMapProducer.put(HazelcastMapProducer.java:125)
at org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.map.HazelcastMapProducer.process(HazelcastMapProducer.java:60)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:814)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.access$200(MulticastProcessor.java:84)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:314)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code that I used was almost similar to what was there is camel docs http://camel.apache.org/hazelcast-component.html

**The following is the code which produces the data to hazelcast**

```
The following is the code snippet that I have used to produce the data to hazelcast in camel:

    from("direct:hazelCast")
        .setHeader(HazelcastConstants.OPERATION, constant(HazelcastConstants.PUT_OPERATION))
        .setHeader(HazelcastConstants.OBJECT_ID, constant("SOME BLA BLA"))
        .split()
        .tokenizeXML(<SOMEValidTag>).streaming()
        .unmarshal(jaxb)
        .convertBodyTo(<Valid>.class)
        .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
        .toF("hazelcast:%stestHazel", HazelcastConstants.MAP_PREFIX);
```

**Note: We need to convert the body to class which is should be serializeable**

Comment: Updated with snippet that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the objectid it is missing

Comment: Where should I set the objectID?  May be a dum question.

Comment: set it in the header